# Spring Boot Batch - execluding JobLauncherCommandLineRunner

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

i have a simple Spring Batch job configured in Spring Boot (something similar to [the spring guides](http://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/)).  at startup, it auto-detects and invokes JobLauncherCommandLineRunner and i want to stop that behavior.  I want the job to only be fired by a defined trigger elsewhere in the app, not on startup.

i've tried the `@ComponentScan(excludeFilters...` approach but it still gets invoked.

any way to switch off this 'helper' class?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set `spring.batch.job.enabled=false` or you can set `spring.batch.job.names=none` (see [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration.java) for details).

Comment: is the list of available properties published anywhere?  This information would be extremely useful.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties

Comment: amazing. thanks.  it's great to see all properties, across spring projects, in a single place.