# how to decide when batch it's starting

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a spring boot 2 application with spring batch.

Actually when application start, batch is started.

Instead of launching it automatically, I would like to start after a file has been created or modified.

what I need to do to have full control of the batch starting?

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Configuration
public class CsvFileToDatabaseConfig {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Billings> billingeReader() {
        ....
    }

    @Bean
    ItemProcessor<Billings, Billings> billingProcessor() {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Billings> billingWriter() {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    public Step csvFileToDatabaseStep() {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    Job csvFileToDatabaseJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) {
        ....
    }

}
```

Comment: There is difference, File creation or modification are the `event`, you have to capture the events and then trigger the batch job. Batch job on it's own cannot execute automatically if not scheduled one.

Comment: The answer by @Stefan Reisner is correct, once you disabled the automatic job launching at startup with `spring.batch.jobs.enabled=false`, it is up to you to detect when the file is created/modified and use a JobLauncher to run the job when appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question has two parts:
To disable `JobLauncherCommandLineRunner` that is responsible for launching jobs at startup, set `spring.batch.jobs.enabled=false` (see also [Spring Boot Batch - execluding JobLauncherCommandLineRunner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27752434/4767829)).
To launch a job from your application logic, inject the `JobLauncher` bean and pass its launch method your job bean together with appropriate job parameters.

Comment: I mistyped; the method to launch the job is called `JobLauncher.run`